# Custom Windows Eventlog, register one source in multiple eventlogs

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, eventlog-source, custom-eventlog

Is it possible, for example to have a source "MyApp" and register it to Application eventlog and another custom eventlog?

Comment: This question needs a bit more detail but I simply structured the quesiton in a clearer way.

Comment: what details do you need?

Comment: So it's a simple question, I want my Application to write to the Application log and to the a custom log..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  If you provide more details then perhaps we could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: why did you post this as an answer? It should really be a comment.